# MongoDb - Equivalent for traditional update-set-where

Tags: mongodb

Does mongo have an equivalent for

```
update emp
set sal = sal * 1.20
where empno in (1,2,3);
```

Note that I want the matched records sal.

```
db.users.update(
    { empno: { $in: [1,2,3]} },
    { $set: { sal: $matched.sal * 1.20 } }, # Not real syntax
    { multi: true }
)
```

I have looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything. I can do it with find-save but I am dealing with a large collection and multi  update will be a more desirable solution.

Answer (score 1):

In mongo shell there is no such function as multiply element. There are few [field update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) operators, but in your situation you need to run a custom `forEach` script:

```
db.users.find({ empno: { $in: [1,2,3]} }).forEach(function(e) {
    e.sal = e.sal * 1.2;
    db.users.save(e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The multiplication wasn't the objective. I just want to do a bulk update without modifying and saving a record at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with MongoDB. The closes you could get is with `$where` operator, but reference [specifically warns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where) against updating documents from `$where`. So, yes, you will have to fetch documents one by one and perform updates individually.